# React - Execute a callback function in Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I was playing with some react form and i came up with a code on which i wanted some advice, as i don't know if it's a good practice or not...

I understand the child to parent communication by passing the parent function via the props to child component, so the Child can call the parent function. But here i added a callback in the Parent function in order to execute a Child function as callback.

```js
/*
 * 1. fill the name input value
 * 2. click submit button
 */
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}

// Parent Component
function Parent() {
  const handleSubmit = (values, callback) => {
    // Do some async stuff with the values
    // Then execute the callback to call resetInput Child function
    callback();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child onHandleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Child Component
function Child(props) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onHandleSubmit(inputValue, () => resetInput());
  };

  const resetInput = () => {
    console.log('clear Input value');
    setInputValue('');
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name :
        <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

1. Child call Parent function onHandleSubmit via props but i add a callback function to the handleSubmit function
2. Parent execute some code and execute the callback to call resetInput in Child component

I made an example on stackblitz, if not clear enough...
So the question is, executing a child function as callback from Parent component sounds ok to you, is it a good pattern ?

Thanks for your time !

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sqzwb8?devtoolsheight=33&embed=1&file=src/Parent.js

Comment: Yes. It's ok....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code's fine, but i would still almost never use this pattern. The reason is that the parent very rarely needs to have that level of control over when the reset logic gets executed, and by using other approaches the components can be less coupled.

In most cases, i would just have onHandleSubmit return a promise, and then run the reset logic on the next line:

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  await props.onHandleSubmit(inputValue);
  resetInput();
};
```

Or if the parent needs to tell the child whether to reset, i'd have the promise resolve to a boolean.

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const shouldReset = await props.onHandleSubmit(inputValue);
  if (shouldReset) {
    resetInput();
  }
};
```

I would only resort to the callback version if, say, some parents needed to execute the code before they did their work, others needed to run it in the middle, others needed to run it 5 times in a loop, and other such variations. But that's very rare.